# Text align doesn't work as supposed

Tags: html, css

If you look at the Nutela image, it's parent has `text-align: center;`, but still it does not move the image to the center but a bit right.

```css
.banner-img {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-img">

  <img src="http://2alkk028sg9z46cvf24elwx2.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/nutella-754483_640.jpg" />

</div>
```

Whats going on here?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Text-align center on an image doesn't work like that. Use `margin: 0 auto` instead.

Comment: @KeesSonnema — Text align center on a parent's image works *exactly* like that. Auto margins won't work because the image isn't display: block.

Comment: Edit: works just fine here?

Comment: Whatever the problem is, it isn't in the code you've shared with us.

Comment: The above snippet works just fine.. you might have other CSS rules acting upon this div,

Comment: @Quentin Sorry I misunderstood. it works fine here.

Comment: @Quentin the code work there because you put jsfiddle with nothing but the the parent and the image.. in the site there are a lot of bootstrap css and parent theme css that may cause the problem, that's why I put the site, the power of inspect element. Anyway now that you've delete the site the question is unrelevent.

Comment: @Avishay28 — Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: Agree with Quentin. You can't provide us a code that works fine and you tell us that's wrong.

Comment: Look at the edit history. He did provide a link to his page. While this is not nice in general it was such a specific example that he was probably not able to work out a MCVE

Comment: @Questions but now for example in order to make jsfiddle that match exactly this site it can take me hours of work on that jsfiddle (this site includes a lot of css rules and overrides).

Comment: Doesn't matter. Stackoverflow have got tons of terabytes of database available for you. Adding a working example here (stacksnippets preffered) is bulletproof for the future (in the future the link may not be available). This is a site to help as much users as possible with the same question+answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their is nothing wrong with image the problem is with your outer div `.banner-img`  you need to add `float: left; width: 100%;`  and every thing will be fine or you can add  `overflow: hidden; width: 100%;`

Comment: what is the problem??

Comment: This works. It's centering the image inside the container now.

Comment: @AdnanAkram works thanks! can you please explain me what cause the unexpected behavior?

Comment: This is a really weird solution. If you need to put float to the parent to center an **inline** element (that's `<img>`) there's something really wrong in the whole code.

Comment: At least on my end the image still doesn't seem to be centered with this solutions (seems to be off to the left)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I go with the other solution, put `overflow: hidden` to the parent and now the image is in the center

Comment: @Avishay28 is the same weird solution. I think the real good solution is to put `float: none` to the image inside the box. The problem is that bootstrap is floating your image to the left. Floats are crap, antique anachronist crap.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude So you say boostrap is crap? :p they saved me hours of hours of making sites responsive..

Comment: Bootstrap's old behaviour is crap in the year 2016. Using floats to layout is crap. Next version of bootstrap will be with flexbox, but right now still is oldest behaviour. The best framework is [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) (take a look) and it works with flexbox for layouts. Floats to layouts was for compatibilize IE6/7 because inlineblocks doesn't work. But now is non-understandable.

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't figure out what was causing that behaviour, but one option to center a div is:

```
.parent
{
    position: relative;
}

.centered
{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote? This is a valid solution.